# Is the following application of Kant's Categorical Imperative valid?

Tags: ethics, kant, categorical-imperative

I'm reading about Kantian ethics and my question is if the maxim/prescription "Increase my Darwinian Fitness" is valid according to Kant's Categorical Imperative.

Comment: Probably not; see [Categorical Imperative](https://www.iep.utm.edu/kantview/#SH5b) : "If it is possible to will that everyone act according to that maxim, then the action under consideration is morally permissible. If it is not possible to will that everyone act according to that maxim, the action is morally impermissible. "

Comment: It is possible to will that everyone act accordting to the maxim "increase my darwinian fitness", therefore the action "increasing my darwinian fitness" is morally permissible. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Since Darwinian fitness is the genetic contribution of an individual relative to the average for the population everyone increasing it would defeat the purpose. Moreover, exploding population that might result is not really what one could reasonably will.

Comment: Hmm, my question is not about your opinion on what my maxim should be, but about validity.

Comment: According to Kant, your maxim needs to makes sense and be universalizable. This one is neither, and therefore "invalid".

Comment: Hmm, "Act only according to that maxim whereby you can, at the same time, will that it should become a universal law." doesn't seem to mention "making sense". Have you read about Kantian ethics?

Comment: Have you read Kant, and in particular the name of the book this quote is from? Did you look at the surrounding context, or just pasted the quote from Mauro's comment? Do you expect to understand Kant by pulling out isolated quotes and interpreting them based on modern dictionaries? Like everything in Kant, the "willing" is subject to reason, he endorses neither nonsense, nor random whim. And you'll have to read a lot more than English translations of popular quotes to understand what they mean.

Comment: Can you explain how darwinian fitness is "nonsense". Everything I "will" is subject to reason because willing presupposes a reason for the willed outcome. If what I will is to increase my darwinian fitness, then I used reason to will that prescription. I will the maxim "increase my darwinian fitness" to become universal.

Comment: It isn't Darwinian fitness that is nonsensical but treating it as a basis for an individual directive that can be used in a universalizable maxim. What sense does it make for everyone to exceed the average?

Comment: @Conifold, the average cannot be exceeded by everyone. "Average" equals the sum of all elements of a set over the number of elements in said set. The universal maxim "increase my darwinian fitness" does not say "everyone must exceed the average darwinian fitness". Regardless, an increase in the average darwinian fitness is necessary to avoid extinction as time-under-extinction-risk increases.

Comment: @AntiTruthist: You just a) made exactly the same point as Conifold and b) demonstrated your misunderstanding of his comments. He said that if *everyone* maximised the abundance of their specific genotype in the following generation (no matter if relative or absolute, this is the very definition of (Darwinian) fitness), this would a) be running against the purpose of maximising the fitness since all other genotypes would be more abundant as well (contradiction in conception) and b) cannot be willed because of overpopulation as the result (contradiction in will). Thus, it is doubly invalid.

Comment: Reference for the above contradictions: *Groundwork for the Metaphysics of Morals*, 4:424.3-10, named as such by Korsgaard [here](https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3201869/Korsgaard_KantForumulaUniversalLaw.pdf?sequence=2). By the way, increasing average Darwinian fitness means nothing but having more children per capita, which means faster population growth, something that arguably brings us to the edge of extinction *faster*. Get your concepts straight before questioning one's understanding of Kant. You obviously have not understood what Darwinian fitness is or how it is defined.

Comment: Just because children per capita increases, does not mean that you can't have more children per capita. Also, you assume that a universal maxim is universally fulfilled when that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: It is not me who assumes anything, it is Kant. If any maxim is the maxim of all wills, this means that every human that is able to act according to that maxim does so. In the case of "maximise your Darwinian fitness", every person that is *able* to procreate and sustain the offspring biologically does so as much as possible to maximally distribute one's genotype - according to the definition of Darwinian fitness. Whether this can or will be realised is irrelevant in Kant, this is all about *conceptual* contradictions, including contradiction in will (the will is causality from freedom).

Answer (score 3):

Finding out whether a proposed maxim is, in fact, a valid categorical imperative goes something like this:

1. Suppose everyone followed the maxim, **x**.
2. If everyone followed the **x**, does a contradiction in terms result?
3. If a contradiction results, **x** is not a valid maxim. Otherwise, **x** is a valid maxim.

An Example:

Suppose lying were always justified and that all people lied constantly without ever telling the truth. Since lies are all that exist in this scenario, you couldn't logically define what the truth is to another person, because your definition must be untrue (*everyone*, including you, *always* lies.) So, in your attempt to define the truth, you produce another lie. Thus, communication becomes an exercise in fantasy where even describing what the truth is becomes impossible; there would be no need for a word like "truth." Without a concept of truth, the concept of a lie (the absence of truth) no longer makes sense either. This is a contradiction in terms: assuming everyone always lies, lying then becomes impossible.

However, if everyone told always told the truth, we would not have this same contradiction in terms. I could simply prefix any lie with the statement, "This is a lie: (insert lie here)." In this scenario, where everyone tells the truth all the time, the logical definition of a lie still makes sense, because one person can reliably communicate the properties of a lie to another person; the fact that everyone always tells the truth guarantees this.

---

So, to answer your question, we replace **x** in the three steps outlined above with the candidate-maxim "Each individual is obligated to increase their own Darwinian fitness." Suppose this maxim were adopted by all people, would that result in the breakdown of the definition of "increasing Darwinian fitness"?

Well, it's not yet clear what that definition is. Only after we have a precise definition of the candidate maxim can we attempt to derive a contradiction. How do we measure Darwinian Fitness? Is it probability of survival? Is it the ability to pass genes on to the next generation? What if you have two individuals, one who is healthy but relatively infertile, while the other agent is sickly, but fertile. Which agent is considered more fit?

Let's suppose you're talking about probability of survival (with fertility assumed equal for all individuals.) If that's the case, survival in what context (On Earth, Mars, the tropics, the arctic)? Some adaptations that are helpful in some environments can be detrimental in others. An additional complicating factor is the role [group selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_selection) has in an individual's survival. When each individual in a group is helped by others, the group, as a whole, generally has a better survival rate than any lone individual. But, sometimes individuals can cheat to increase their own potential for survival (perhaps by hoarding resources.) Who's more fit, the team player or the cheater?

It's not possible to have a conversation about the validity of this maxim, until the maxim is better defined. However, I'll anticipate where I think you were going with this with a discussion of "positive duties." It's been taken, in [perfectionist ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectionism_(philosophy)), that Kant generally supported the idea of improving one's self:

> Positive duties, by contrast, are duties to exercise one’s capacity to develop one’s nature and/or to realize perfectionist goods. For example, one has a duty to develop one’s talents and not to devote one’s life entirely to idleness and pleasure (Kant 1785). [source](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/perfectionism-moral/#SelRegDut)

*(Kant 1785) Refers to *The Metaphysics of Morals*

However, this has little to do with notions of perfection relating to "Darwinian Fitness" and more to do with with an individual achieving [Eudaimonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia). Supposing you had a working definition of "Darwinian Fitness," you would need to argue that maximizing fitness is [either an objective good or that fitness is somehow an expression of human nature](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/perfectionism-moral/#TwoVerPer). But again, it all starts with the definition; without a clear-cut definition of fitness that can differentiate between objectively fit and unfit individuals, any argument (Kantian or otherwise) is invalid. My suspicion is that such an objective definition of individual fitness is impossible, because fitness changes depending on the environment, which means for a single individual, there are as many definitions of fitness as there are environments.

Comment: In a world where everyone lies to eachother, lies are just that which are communicated; very defined. Making sense of a definition/concept does not necessitate communication. [Regardless, "darwinian fitness" is defined](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+darwinian+fitness). Gravity changes depending on the environment, yet gravity is defined. Your eudaimonia necessitates extinction-avoidance. Human nature (and the concept of good/bad) is an evolved construct, so human nature/good/bad is an expression of fitness. You seem to be relying on evolved constructs to doubt evolved constructs....

Comment: “Lies are just which are communicated; very defined” well, not quite. The point is that when a lie becomes a synonym for speech, the definition of “lie” has changed. So it’s no longer possible to lie, in the way we understand lying. That’s the general idea of Kant’s categorical imperative, to prove logically (in terms of definitions and deduction, rather than looking at he consequences of maxims on individuals, which would be consequentialism) If you’re interested in learning more about Kant’s categorical imperative, I would recommend “Exploring Philosophy” edited by Steven M. Cahn.

Comment: Yes, you’re right, Darwinian evolution, like gravity, is defined in terms of environmental context. The thing is, categorical imperatives, unlike natural laws, are not flexible to context. What is right is right regardless of context in Kantian ethics.

Comment: Here’s a simple example: suppose I want to buy the best computer I can. What does best mean? Let’s say best performance for the money. However, some aspects of performance are in direct conflict like battery life and processor speed. Fast processors use a lot of energy. So I can’t prescribe a singular rule “the best computer is x” because what works for one person might not work for another.

Comment: Also the definition you linked to doesn’t fit the bill for a categorical imperative. When I said the definition you supplied isn’t well defined, I didn’t mean there wasn’t a dictionary definition for Darwinian Fitness. What I meant was that, relative to the categorical imperative, your maxim needs to be more specific. It needs to address (at least) the issues raised in my answer. Why? Because a categorical imperative is a single rule that goes for all cases. “Never lie” is an example. Can you provide an example of a single rule that always promotes “fitness” in all contexts?

Comment: “Eudaimonia necessitates extinction-avoidance” great, that’s the start of a good argument. Drawing upon frameworks built by others to justify your position. Although I might add that extinction avoidance is not the same thing as pursuing the best fitness. There’s a difference between quasi-eugenics and saving the earth from an asteroid. Also,  all of philosophy is “evolved constructs doubting evolved constructs.” Only I might also say that philosophy wasn’t so much a product of evolution, but of people building new ideas entirely. There was nothing like Kant before him.

Comment: you can prescribe the singular rule "get the computer that increases your darwinian fitness" which applies to all cases. Philosophy is just prescriptions and descriptions, both of which are very much evolved constructs. Just because the way in which, and what, we prescribe/describe changes does not mean we didn't evolve to prescribe/describe. You also contradict yourself: "the point is that when a "not-lie" becomes a synonym for speech, the definition of “not-lie” has changed." Thanks for your effort, anyway.

Comment: Yes that’s the point; an invalid categorical imperative results in a contradiction. In the case of always lying, a contradiction is found, while always telling the truth it isn’t.    That’s how we know always telling the truth is a valid maxim and always lying isn’t. It’s an extremely common (some might say basic or fundamental) thought experiment in Kantian Ethics. For more on Kant, the anthology I mentioned previously is good, but I also suggest this book: https://www.introducingbooks.com/ib-title/introducing-kant/

Comment: Kantian ethics is a hard topic and, as other commenters have mentioned, his work deserves a serious treatment. Some philosophers spend their whole lives studying Kant. If you’re interested, I encourage you to read an anthology—some companion text or summary of Kant— and then move on to his original texts (which are extremely dense.)

Comment: You must have misread my comment. "not-lie" does not mean "lying".

Comment: No I understood. I just reiterated my previous point (which incidentally isn’t my point, but Kant’s) about the “always tell the truth” being  an example of a categorical imperative.

Comment: Really, although we can be abrasive at times on stackexchange, people on this site are out to help others.  Consider my advice and further your reading on Kant. The categorical imperative is a subtle concept and I think you’d benefit from a deeper reading of the topic.

Comment: the categorical imperative is just a rephrased version of the golden rule, both of which are invalid.